# Append HTML data jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5.3

This time I wrote html in controller when I check a checkbox I get data in console but I want to get it in the form.

I have checkbox in foreach loop

```
<input type='checkbox' value='{$student['id']}' name='student_ids[]' id='chkbx' required> {$student['name']}
```

when click on checkboxes data load accordingly

its my html

```
    $str .= '<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">
    Student
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="students-clicked" class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple name="students[]">
            <option value=""></option>';
            foreach ($students as $students) {
                $str .= "<option value='{$student->id}'>{$student->name}</option>";
            }

$str .=         '</select>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Jquery Method is as

```
    $('body').on('click', "#chkbx", function() {
    var class = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    $.ajax({
            url: '/trigger/studentsData',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'trigger_type': 'click' , ids: class},
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
});
```

Except jQuery everything is written in controller this time I am getting HTML data in console how can I append it in my html form it should also update according to checkbox selection

Comment: Dont write html in controller.

Comment: @Kyslik it requirement here in my case that'ts why i am using this approach

Comment: you want to show your html after checkboxes?

Comment: yes above html in my question changes on chekboxes selection i want to show that div in my form

Comment: see my answer @bluemoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<input type='checkbox' value='{$student['id']}' name='student_ids[]' id='chkbx' required/> {$student['name']}
<div id="appendata">
 //your ajax data
</div>
```

Now in Success Function

```
success: function(result) {
    $("#appendata").html(result); // this will replace when you select the checkbox
         or
    $("#appendata").append(result); // this will append when you select again from checkbox
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: its close to solution but not exact its insert 5 html fields if i check 5 checboxes it should give all data in one dropdown

Comment: if i click 2nd checkbox it should insert data in same field not need to insert new

Comment: then you have to do changes in your html that is to be used in controller. i have give answer according to your problem now you have to look your code

Comment: then use html(result);

Comment: yes i got it its still inset whole div once mean total 2 times and keep changing data in last one mean 2nd div it should show only one

Comment: thanks +1 for help please also vote question if you think it should :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) rather use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to override the content with the response data

```
success: function (result) {
    $("#container").html(result);
}
```

Plus, if you have more than one checkboxes, don't use `id`, rather use `class` attribute to loop through them

Comment: thanks +1 for help please also vote question if you think it should :)